# Javascript regex filter list on partial dynamic matches

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a list in react that on key up the list can be filtered. My handler currently looks like this - but it only works on whole word matches and blanks on a result when the user starts typing or starts to add spaces to type the remaining words.

```
initialCommands: [
        {
          "label": "Order more plasters",
          "icon": ShoppingCart
        },
        {
          "label": "Book a meeting with my doctor",
          "icon": Bell
        }
      ]
```

[image]

```
  typeHandler(data){
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${data.command})\\b`, "gi");

    const result = initialCommands.filter(function(item) {
      return item.label.match(regex);
    });

    this.setState({
      prunedCommands: result,
      prunedCommandsReady: true
    });    
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you even need regexp here? Replace it with `includes`. If you want to use regex for some specific reason, remove `\b` which checks for "word boundary" ("full words only"), which is exactly what you want to get rid of.

Comment: this changes the functionality to only work if the full sentence is typed it, so its even worse.

Comment: Not sure if you are reinventing a wheel or there is smth else. Try this `new RegExp('.*${data.command}.*', "gi")`, if not provide some kind of expected input/output using code snippet, cause I'm not sure what is your problem.
Not sure why you cannot simply do this: `return item.label.includes(data.command)`

Comment: That worked - thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the regex needs to be updated. Try adding something like the following, note the period and asterisk.

```
\\b(${data.command}).*\\b
```

Whenever I'm messing with regex, I use this website. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).